# How to typedef an inner class

Tags: c++, templates

I have a matrix class and a column class inside it:

```
template<class T>
struct MatrixT
{
    template<class T>
    struct ColumnT
    {
    };
};
```

Note that a `ColumnT` will always hold the same type as a `MatrixT`.

For convenience I define

```
typedef MatrixT<double> matrix;
```

Since in reality, I'll be using a `double` element most of the time. But I also want to define something similar for the `columnT` class. I tried

```
typedef MatrixT<double>::ColumnT<double> matrix::column;
```

but compilation fails with the error

> Error - qualified name is not allowed

Is there a way of achieving what I want?

I'd like to be able to type `matrix::column c;` just as I can type `matrix m;`

Comment: did you try `MatrixT<double>::ColumnT`
the parameter T might be shadowed, since both templates use the same placeholder for the type. try different names for T as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove the second `template<class T>`

```
template<class T>
struct MatrixT
{
    struct ColumnT
    {
    };
};
```

`ColumnT` should then be using the same type as `MatrixT`, and your typedef...

```
typedef MatrixT<double> matrix;
```

...should work as you are expecting it to.